# Show that $|x_{(k)} - y_{(k)}| \leq \|x-y\|_2$

Tags: inequality

Given two vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, show that the absolute difference in the $k^{th}$ order statistics is bounded above by the $\ell_2$ norm.

More formally, consider $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$. Show that:

$$|x_{(k)} - y_{(k)}| \leq \|x-y\|_2$$

**my attempt**

By a union bound on the LHS, it is sufficient to show that this is true for the sum of the squared deviations of the order statistics. So we aim to show that:

$$\underbrace{\sum (x_{(k)} - y_{(k)})^2}_{(A)} \leq \underbrace{\sum (x_{(k)} - y_k)^2}_{(B)}$$

where we have used the fact that we can rearrange the coordinates of $y$ without loss of generality.

First, I claim that swapping $y_i$ and $y_{i+j}$ for $i, j :0<j\leq n-i$ decreases the value $(B)$ above if and only if $y_i > y_{i+j}$. So, the value $(B)$ is minimized when the coordinates of $y$ are ordered. This is simply the value $(A)$ above.

Now to prove the claim. The value $(B)$ decreases when swapping $y_i$ and $y_{i+j}$ if and only if:

$$(x_{(i)} - y_{i+j})^2 + (x_{(i+j)} - y_{i})^2 < (x_{(i)} - y_{i})^2 + (x_{(i+j)} - y_{i+j})^2$$

Simplifying, this is equivalent to:

$$x_{(i)}y_{i+j} + x_{(i+j)}y_i > x_{(i)}y_i + x_{(i+j)}y_{i+j}$$

But this is true if and only if $y_{i+j} < y_i$, by the rearrangement inequality. So we are done.

**My question**

I could use some feedback on my proof. Specifically, is there a more direct way to show the claim rather than using a union bound as I have done?